# How to format object output

Tags: javascript, object

When I print this out in my webpage:

```
var computer = {
  "Home":{
    "Desktop":{
        value:"Result"
    },
    "Documents":{
    },
    "Downloads":{
    },
    "Library":{
    },
    "Movies":{
    },
    "Music":{
    },
    "Pictures":{
    },
    "Library":{
    },
    "Downloads":{
    },
    "Files":{
    },
    "Devices":{
    },
    "USB":{
    },
    "Hard_Drive":{
    }
  },
}
```

i get this:

```
{"Desktop":{"value":"Result"},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{}," //blah blah blah
```

how do I format it so the output looks like the original code? aka the first piece of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify(jsonobj, null, 2)` if you want to do it dynamically from javascript, The third argument tells javascript how many spaces to use when pretty printing the json obj.

```js
varcomputer={"Home":{"Desktop":{value:"Result"},"Documents":{},"Downloads":{},"Library":{},"Movies":{},"Music":{},"Pictures":{},"Library":{},"Downloads":{},"Files":{},"Devices":{},"USB":{},"Hard_Drive":{}}}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(varcomputer, 0, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```